# How can I prevent that Rails' form helpers to sanitize or transform my string for name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make that

```
label_tag "{{myVariable}}", "My Variable"
```

have the following output

```
<label for="{{myVariable}}">
   My Variable    
</label>
```

The form helper is turning into _ _ myvariable _ _

Answer (score 0):

try this `label_tag nil, "My Variable", :for=> "{{myVariable}}"`